# Reaching the result provided by another class's method

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm making an RSS Reader and I'm having trouble with keeping the MVVM and the communication between classes.

I have a ViewModel, there is a list of items which I'd like to bind to the View, call it Items.

There is another class, a FeedReader which would provide the items for the Items list. At least that's my goal. FeedReader has the following methods:

```
    public void GetFeed(Uri uri)
    {
        // that's all it does:
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadStringCompleted);
        webClient.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
     }

    private void webClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
    // the async method finished
    // calls UpdateFeed:
            UpdateFeed(e.Result);
    }

    private List<ItemViewModel> UpdateFeed(string feedXML)
    {
    // parsing the string
    // LINQ to XML query does the rest, creates new Model items, put them in a list with .ToList()

    //return this result List:

        return feedItems;
    }
```

These methods work fine.

In the ViewModel I call the FeedReader's GetFeed(Uri) with an uri. I would like to fill the Items list with the provided items. The problem is that the method which provide the items is the UpdateFeed and I did not call that, I called GetFeed.

```
        var feed = new FeedReader();
        feed.GetFeed(uri);
```

How can I reach UpdateFeed's result in the ViewModel? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've deleted my answer since it doesn't seem to be helping this conversation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a taskcompletionsource to make it awaitable ;

```
public Task<List<Foo>> GetFeed(Uri uri)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<List<Foo>>(); //used to transform a synchronous method into an asynchronous.
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
    webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += async(sender,e)=>
    {
        tcs.SetResult(e.Result); //Method ended, can now return. 
    };
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

And in your view model :

```
var feed = new FeedReader();
var listFoo = feed.GetFeed(uri);

//UpdateFeed
```

And then you will be able to work with those data in your view model.
Regards